# Multiple "If" statements in a batch file

Tags: batch-file, if-statement

I was making a batch program but i do not know the command for something like this:

```
IF EXIST "folder_a" AND IF EXIST "folder_b" AND IF EXIST "folder_c" THEN DO
(
    Some Code
)
```

Note that was not correct syntax/correct program commands.

If anyone knows the command please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several small errors in your code. Note that in Batch files:

- `IF` command does NOT use `THEN` word.
- `DO` word is a part of `FOR` command, not `IF`.
- In an `IF`, you must put the desired command *in the same line* of the `IF`. If you want to insert several commands enclosed in parentheses, the opening parentheses must be placed in the same line of the `IF`.

This is an example of a valid IF:

```
IF EXIST "folder_a" (
    Some Code
)
```

In an `IF` command you may only use NOT before the condition, but there is no way to combine *two conditions* with AND, OR, etc. However, you may nest another `IF` command into the first one:

```
IF EXIST "folder_a" IF EXIST "folder_b" IF EXIST "folder_c" (
    Some Code
)
```

However, you *may* write previous code in a slightly clearer way with the aid of a small trick:

```
SET AND=IF
IF EXIST "folder_a" %AND% EXIST "folder_b" %AND% EXIST "folder_c" (
    Some Code
)
```

**NOTE**: You must be aware that previous line imply *three individual* `IF` commands! This means that you can NOT use `ELSE` part because it belongs just to the *last* IF:

```
SET AND=IF
IF EXIST "folder_a" %AND% EXIST "folder_b" %AND% EXIST "folder_c" (
    ECHO The three folders exists
) ELSE (
    ECHO folder_a and folder_b exists, but folder_c not
)
```

Comment: Thank you, that was very informative. However, my 'code' was what I actually wanted to do, I wasn't going to put that in my batch file :)

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
if exist "folder_a" if exist "folder_b" if exist "folder_c" (do something...)
```